# Opencv-Python-Resizing image

Tags: python, opencv, image-resizing

Tryin'to resize the image but got an error saying.

> **TypeError**: resize() missing 1 required positional argument: 'image'.

```
line 11, in <module> img = resize(img, width = 1280)
```

---

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def resize(self,image,window_height = 500):
    aspect_ratio = float(image.shape[1])/float(image.shape[0])
    window_width = window_height/aspect_ratio
    image = cv2.resize(image, (int(window_height),int(window_width)))
    return image

img = cv2.imread('hr.jpg')
img_resized = resize(img,window_height = 800)
cv2.imshow("Resized",img_resized)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Which line did the error come on?
You can read more about asking questions here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: line 11, in <module>  img = resize(img, width = 1280)

Comment: [Edit] your Question to add requested informations

Answer (score 4):

You need to say the height and the width too. :)

```
resized_image = cv2.resize(image, (800, 250)) # for example
```

First is width (800) and the second is height (250)

**EDIT**
Maybe your code can work (I don't know) but you have forgotten `cv2.` before resize but I recomend you write width and height.

Answer (score 1):

The function `resize(image, window_height)` that you defined is not a method, so it should not have the `self` argument.

```
import cv2

def resize(image, window_height = 500):
    aspect_ratio = float(image.shape[1])/float(image.shape[0])
    window_width = window_height/aspect_ratio
    image = cv2.resize(image, (int(window_height),int(window_width)))
    return image
```

When removing `self`, your code runs.